# Route traffic through floating ip

Tags: iptables, ip, nat, kubernetes, heartbeat

I have a (kubernetes) cluster (3 servers, ips 172.20.10.[10,11,12]), and between them their is 1 floating ip (172.20.10.20).
My provider has an 1:1 NAT for an dedicated public ip to the floating ip.
All the floating ip thing works perfectly (when the one with the ip goes down, one of the others assume the ip), in a way that only one has the ip at any time.
All incoming traffic also works, BUT lets go the the issue.

All outgoing traffic is coming from the individual ips 172.20.10.[10,11,12], so the providers nat it to an generic public ip. But I want the traffic to come from the floating ip (from all 3 hosts).
Searching I found that MAYBE an NAT would be a solution, but I don't know if it would work, all on the same network.

```
All 3 hosts having the floating ip as gateway, and on all 3 have the iptables rules
to nat the traffic from them to the real gateway masking to the floating ip, would this work?
```

Does any one has any other suggestions?

Comment: I think it could work, definitely you should try it. Let community know if that worked for you, if not we will try to find another way.